# Convert json to csv in R: only one row loads

Tags: r

Hi I am using the below code to convert a json file to csv.

```
library(rjson)
data1 <- fromJSON(file="Desktop/myfulldata.json")
j_data <- as.data.frame(data1)
write.csv(j_data, "my4.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

my json file contains:

```
[{"Status":"COMPLIANT","InstalledTime":"","ExecutionType":"","PatchSeverity":"","Title":"","Severity":"UNSPECIFIED","ExecutionTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:53Z","captureTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:58Z","schemaVersion":"1.0"},
{"Status":"COMPLIANT","InstalledTime":"2014-03-18T00:00:00.0000000Z","ExecutionType":"Command","PatchSeverity":"Critical","Title":"Windows (KB2919355)","Severity":"UNSPECIFIED","ExecutionTime":"2019-05-22T11:56:58Z","captureTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:58Z","schemaVersion":"1.0"},
{"Status":"COMPLIANT","InstalledTime":"2014-10-15T00:00:00.0000000Z","ExecutionType":"Command","PatchSeverity":"Important","Title":"Security (KB2977765)","Severity":"UNSPECIFIED","ExecutionTime":"2019-05-22T11:56:58Z","captureTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:58Z","schemaVersion":"1.0"}]
```

My file has many rows, but my output is only one row.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please send a example of "myfulldata.json" so we can reproduce and help you

Comment: @PedroHenriqueS I have added it along with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Exemple taken from the documentation of the package `jsonlite` (package used in `httr` to handle jsons) :

```r
library(jsonlite)
# Stringify some data
jsoncars <- toJSON(mtcars, pretty=TRUE)
cat(jsoncars)

# Parse it back
fromJSON(jsoncars)

# Parse escaped unicode
fromJSON('{"city" : "Z\\u00FCrich"}')
```

**EDIT** : with the provided data :

```r
# --- with provided data
library(jsonlite)
dframe <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = "question_so_json.json")
dframe

# Run this to write csv
utils::writes.csv(x = dframe, file = "mydata.csv")
```

**data**

```r
[{
        "Status":"COMPLIANT",
        "InstalledTime":"",
        "ExecutionType":"",
        "PatchSeverity":"",
        "Title":"",
        "Severity":"UNSPECIFIED",
        "ExecutionTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:53Z",
        "captureTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:58Z",
        "schemaVersion":"1.0"
},
{
        "Status":"COMPLIANT",
        "InstalledTime":"2014-03-18T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "ExecutionType":"Command",
        "PatchSeverity":"Critical",
        "Title":"Windows (KB2919355)",
        "Severity":"UNSPECIFIED",
        "ExecutionTime":"2019-05-22T11:56:58Z",
        "captureTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:58Z",
        "schemaVersion":"1.0"
},
{
        "Status":"COMPLIANT",
        "InstalledTime":"2014-10-15T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "ExecutionType":"Command",
        "PatchSeverity":"Important",
        "Title":"Security (KB2977765)",
        "Severity":"UNSPECIFIED",
        "ExecutionTime":"2019-05-22T11:56:58Z",
        "captureTime":"2019-05-22T12:46:58Z",
        "schemaVersion":"1.0"
}]
```

Comment: I do not have an escaped column. My issue is that after the first set of row, the data does not read at all.

Comment: I have added the `[]` characters in your question's exemple, I am no json expert but if your source file is missing those it might explain the issue. Also, can you confirm the above code works on your computer ?